# How to create a 3d map for an augmented reality game?

Tags: ios, 3d, camera, augmented-reality

i want to build a game like this one: [AR Invaders](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/ar-invaders/id406133349?mt=8)

how can i create a 3D map? the camera of the iphone should be the middle of the 3D circle map. 
i dont know if 3d circle map is the correct word to explain it.
the iphone should be the object middle of the 3d circle map and around the iphone should be the objects to kill.

so how can i create this augmented reality map, so when i move foreward or backward with the iphone the objects also grow? or when i move the iphone upward?

any suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest to use angles and distances instead of a map since it better represents a 3d sphere and then you can calculate objetives size in terms of distance

Answer (score 0):

Looks like game uses only IMU data and video capture from front camera. If you want to use not only rotations in your game, probably you need some kind of SLAM like this one http://13thlab.com/ballinvasion/